# How set video calling using agora in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io

I want to set channels dynamically because its very hard to tell other to join this channel.

how i can join a channel problematically?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use firebase dynamic links to do this. Where you send a particular invite link to the person and when that link is clicked it automatically fills the channel name.

You can refer this on how to implement this using firebase dynamic links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61558367